# ONE Gmail email is sent and TWO different signatures are added

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Gmail user bill@example.com sends **ONE** email to **TWO** people.

Example:

```
FROM: bill@example.com
TO: alex@example.com, sophie@example
```

Gmelious plugin is able to place **TWO DIFFERENT TRACKING HTML CODES** in one, sent email, e.g.

```
bill - email no code (in bill's Gmail account)
alex - email with code1 (in alex's Gmail account)
sophie - email with code2 (in sophie's Gmail account)
```

How on earth Gmelious is doing this per-recipient tracking in their business plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic here. When you enable per-recipient tracking, two different mail messages are actually sent.

You could verify it by clicking down arrow near reply button in Gmail and selecting "Show original":

[image]

If you compare raw messages received by alex@example.com and sophie@example.com, you will see that they differ:

[image]

In both messages you will see however the same header:

> To: alex@example.com, sophie@example.com

But it shouldn't embarrass you. It's just SMTP header with text value. You could actually deliver message to one recipient and fill `To` header with any other e-mail.

Tracking codes that Gmelius puts to message body also differ that allows to achieve per-recipient tracking.

**UPDATE**

You may be interested how Gmelius plugin is implemented, so that two different mail messages are sent when you actually compose one e-mail. It does it by using rich [Gmail Add-ons API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/). To be more specific, [sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) method of [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) class is used. If you check description of method parameters, you will see that it's possible to provide any subject, body, recipient list and other SMTP headers.

But even with Gmelius plugin, the e-mails are delivered with gmail SMTP servers eventually. Gmelius just transforms original composed e-mail into multiple mail messages with different tracking codes.

**UPDATE** (regarding security concerns)

Gmail Add-ons API does not allow to send e-mails via 3rd party SMTP servers. `sendEmail` method does not have any parameter where you could specify another server. The e-mail is sent in the same way as if you send it from Gmail without Gmelius. Gmelius just splits recipients list and extend body with html tracking codes.

If you still have any doubts regarding origin of e-mail, you could examine raw mail message. There you will see the actual server from which the message came:

[image]

This `Received` header basically says: `mx.google.com` server has received the mail from `mail-sor-f65.google.com`.

Comment: Does it mean that emails are sent via SMTP protocol from third party servers?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details on this aspect.

Comment: My main concern here is the privacy. Is the actual email sent via third party servers. E.g. Gmail ui with plugin -> Gmelious servers -> Gmail App.

Comment: Check addendum to my asnwer.

Comment: Basically the question is more about the email flow. The user presses send button and... I assume the JS plugin is not invoking the sendEmail method directly (my assumption). So some kind of intermediary service is needed to do this. Am I right?

Comment: Gmail add-ons are developed using Apps Script, a scripting language based on JavaScript (https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/). When the user presses send button, Gmelius plugin code is executed. It checks that per-recipient tracking is enabled and invokes `sendEmail` method for each recipient with unique tracking code. All this is executed on client side as JavaScript. `sendEmail` results to AJAX call to gmail application server (not an SMTP server). Gmail application, when processing this AJAX call, enques e-mail for actual sending over SMTP.

Comment: @CodeFuller
When we send multiple emails the sent tab will be filled with multiple emails but as per the user he has sent only one email how to handle the sent tab?